# Automatize archiviation process of an app in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

The project that I'm currently developing consists in two different sub-projects: a xamarin.forms  application and an aspnet core project used by the first. For now I need only the android version of it, so let us focus only on this aspect. The aspnet project should be able to provide a page where the user can download the .apk. For now I've put the .apk file in a folder in the web project directory and all works perfectly. What I want to accomplish now is to automatize this process: everytime i compile the entire solution, the system itself should prepare the apk package and put it in the right folder. At first it seemed easy, but I've not found a way to do it. Doesn't anyone have tried this, yet? Thanks!

Comment: You can define Post-Build events in Visual Studio in the project properties. I haven't done it on a xamarin project but it should be something like `copy "$(TargetPath)" "<destination path>"`.